# Function for finding all distinct values in a table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I need a function for all distinct values in my table in SQL Server.

For example, if my table looks like this:

```
field1   | field2   | ... | field8
---------+----------+-----+---------
valuef11 | valuef21 | ... | valuef81
valuef12 | valuef22 | ... | valuef82
etc...
```

Then I need to return a table with 2 fields as follows:

```
field1 valuef11
field1 valuef12
field1 valuef13
field2 valuef21
field2 valuef22
....
field8 valuef81
field8 valuef82
field8 valuef83
field8 valuef84
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* you are looking for this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 'field1' AS fieldname, field1 FROM yourtable
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT 'field2' AS fieldname, field2 FROM yourtable
UNION ALL
...
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT 'field8' AS fieldname, field8 FROM yourtable
```

Note that this assumes that all fields have the same type.

In SQL Server 2005 or newer you could also use [`UNPIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx):

```
SELECT DISTINCT fieldname, fieldvalue
FROM yourtable
UNPIVOT(fieldvalue FOR fieldname IN
   (field1, field2, ..., field8)
) AS unpvt;
```

Again, this assumes that all fields have the same type.

Comment: your answer i s very good but i need to automatically generate this table because similar table with similar output is very reusable for me

Comment: @jozi: Frankly, it sounds like a really bad idea to do this. Can you explain why you need it?

Comment: i need a store-procedure   for this work via input table name and in output table my explained

Comment: i have 50 table and my users fill it i will to do this work for all table to get unic value  from all my table

Comment: @jozi: Instead of 50 tables is there a good reason why you can't use one table, with a column to say which user's data it is?

Comment: The type of column "Temp" conflicts with the type of other columns specified in the UNPIVOT list.
error

Comment: My answer assumes that all fields have the same type. In SQL Server it is not possible to store data of different types in a single column.

Comment: my type of field is n char but different in length

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `union` wrapped in a `distinct` subquery:

```
select  distinct A
,       B
from    (   
        select field1 as A, field11 as B from YourTable
        union all
        select field1, field12 from YourTable
        union all
        select field1, field13 from YourTable
        union all
        select field2, field21 from YourTable
        union all
        select field2, field22 from YourTable
        ) as SubQueryAlias
```

If your first field is always 6 charachters long, and your second field always 7, you can generate a query like:

```
declare @sql varchar(max)

select  @sql = case 
            when @sql is null then 'select ' + a.name + ' as a, ' + b.name + 
                ' as b from TestTable '
            else @sql + 'union all select ' + a.name + ', ' + b.name + 
                ' from TestTable ' 
            end
from    sys.all_columns a
join    sys.all_columns b
on      len(b.name) = 7
        and substring(b.name,1,6) = a.name
        and b.object_id = a.object_id
where   a.object_id = object_id('TestTable')

set @sql = 'select distinct a, b from (' + @sql + ') as SubQueryAlias'

exec (@sql)
```

Comment: if my table and my filed changed need to overwrite this code but i will not this

Comment: @jozi: One way to do that added, but I'd try to avoid this for a production database

Answer (score 0):

you want to distinct based on 8 fields and show 2 fields.

You'll have repeating pairs if you do that. Is that what you want? or do you want to do a   "Group By" clause?

Cheers!